# Angular loading feedback on button click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've noticed when testing a project on a live server using Angular that there is a small delay between the user submitting a form and anything actually happening (when there is a backend process and database involved). So I'd like to create visual feedback where the button clicked turns into a loading gif or something.

I can't work out how to access the button element through my Angular submit functions.

Say I have this HTML:

```
<form ng-submit="submit(user)">
  <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then this in Angular:

```
$scope.submit = function(user){
  //http requests and whatever else to process the form.
  //how can I access the button element to alter it's visual state?
});
```

I just don't know how to access the button clicked. Ideally I don't want to use specific id's or classes because I want to apply this to all buttons clicked.

I already know how to create the visual style I want, it's just applying it to the relevant element that's an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the ng-style or ng-class (preferred) using a scope variable:

simple style using ng-style:

HTML

```
<form ng-submit="submit(user)">
  <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" />
  <button type="submit" ng-style="{'opacity': buttonOpacity} ">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$scope.buttonOpacity = 0.4;
$scope.submit = function(user){
  //http requests and whatever else to process the form.
  //how can I access the button element to alter it's visual state?
  $scope.buttonOpacity = 0.4;
});
```

Better alternative using ng-class:

HTML

```
<form ng-submit="submit(user)">
  <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" />
  <button type="submit" ng-class="{'myAlteredButtonClass': applyNewButtonClass === true} ">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$scope.applyNewButtonClass = false;
$scope.submit = function(user){
  //http requests and whatever else to process the form.
  //how can I access the button element to alter it's visual state?
  $scope.applyNewButtonClass = true;
});
```

CSS:

```
.myAlteredButtonClass {
    opacity: 1;
    border: 1px solid;
    color: green;
    ... etc.
}
```

Comment: Ah yes the ng-class method seems like a fairly logical solution. I'll use that, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this in Angular.  Among them are [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) and [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf).  Using ng-show, you could do the following:

```
<form ng-submit="submit(user)">
  <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" />
  <button ng-show="!submitted" type="submit">Submit</button>
  <div ng-show="submitted" >Loading spinner here</div>
</form>
```

And

```
$scope.submit = function(user){
  $scope.submitted = true;
});
```

Comment: a good simple solution if you want to show a loading spinner.

Comment: Thanks, this is a solution but in my case I wanted to change the button rather than introduce a new element.

Answer (score -2):

If you give a name to the form you will be able to access its elements:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form#submitting-a-form-and-preventing-the-default-action

Comment: This is not the correct way of altering the view in Angular, this would be using a jQuery-like approach to access the elements. To alter the view from the controller, the correct method is to use ng-class (preferred) or possibly ng-style

Comment: The question is posed with the condition: Ideally I don't want to use specific id's or classes. Moreover, the jquery-style as you said it's part of angular documentation.